# Best way to store a binary search tree node into a graph vertex

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, binary-search-tree

What is the best way to visit each node in a binary search tree, then store each node into vertexes in a graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit from left to right in BST using Queue

```
 private void visit(BSTNode root, Integer from, Integer till) {
            Queue<BSTNode> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
            queue.add(root);
            Graph<Integer> graph = new Graph<>();
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                BSTNode node = queue.poll();
                if (node.getLeft() != null) {
                   graph.addEdge(node, node.getLeft());
                   queue.add(node.getLeft());
                 }

                if (node.getRight() != null) {
                    graph.addEdge(node, node.getRight());
                    queue.add(node.getRight());
                }
            }
        }
```